# add drag option Polar in Echarts by baidu

Tags: javascript, echarts, baidu

I'm using Echarts by Baidu 3.0 and I'm wondering if it is possible to add drag option to a polar chart.
The drag option is explained [here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=line-draggable) I could use it only with the scatter chart.
Here is the Polar chart [example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=scatter-polar-punchCard).
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience over ECharts, but I like to hack codes :P and this was fun (took me an hour).
So, I modified [this example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=scatter-polar-punchCard) for you. Now you can drag stuff around.

Here is the code:

```
var hours = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
        '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
        '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
        '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
var days = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
        'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'];

var data = [[0,0,5],[0,1,1],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0],[0,6,0],[0,7,0],[0,8,0],[0,9,0],[0,10,0],[0,11,2],[0,12,4],[0,13,1],[0,14,1],[0,15,3],[0,16,4],[0,17,6],[0,18,4],[0,19,4],[0,20,3],[0,21,3],[0,22,2],[0,23,5],[1,0,7],[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,4,0],[1,5,0],[1,6,0],[1,7,0],[1,8,0],[1,9,0],[1,10,5],[1,11,2],[1,12,2],[1,13,6],[1,14,9],[1,15,11],[1,16,6],[1,17,7],[1,18,8],[1,19,12],[1,20,5],[1,21,5],[1,22,7],[1,23,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,0],[2,7,0],[2,8,0],[2,9,0],[2,10,3],[2,11,2],[2,12,1],[2,13,9],[2,14,8],[2,15,10],[2,16,6],[2,17,5],[2,18,5],[2,19,5],[2,20,7],[2,21,4],[2,22,2],[2,23,4],[3,0,7],[3,1,3],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[3,4,0],[3,5,0],[3,6,0],[3,7,0],[3,8,1],[3,9,0],[3,10,5],[3,11,4],[3,12,7],[3,13,14],[3,14,13],[3,15,12],[3,16,9],[3,17,5],[3,18,5],[3,19,10],[3,20,6],[3,21,4],[3,22,4],[3,23,1],[4,0,1],[4,1,3],[4,2,0],[4,3,0],[4,4,0],[4,5,1],[4,6,0],[4,7,0],[4,8,0],[4,9,2],[4,10,4],[4,11,4],[4,12,2],[4,13,4],[4,14,4],[4,15,14],[4,16,12],[4,17,1],[4,18,8],[4,19,5],[4,20,3],[4,21,7],[4,22,3],[4,23,0],[5,0,2],[5,1,1],[5,2,0],[5,3,3],[5,4,0],[5,5,0],[5,6,0],[5,7,0],[5,8,2],[5,9,0],[5,10,4],[5,11,1],[5,12,5],[5,13,10],[5,14,5],[5,15,7],[5,16,11],[5,17,6],[5,18,0],[5,19,5],[5,20,3],[5,21,4],[5,22,2],[5,23,0],[6,0,1],[6,1,0],[6,2,0],[6,3,0],[6,4,0],[6,5,0],[6,6,0],[6,7,0],[6,8,0],[6,9,0],[6,10,1],[6,11,0],[6,12,2],[6,13,1],[6,14,3],[6,15,4],[6,16,0],[6,17,0],[6,18,0],[6,19,0],[6,20,1],[6,21,2],[6,22,2],[6,23,6]];

option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Punch Card of Github',
        link: 'https://github.com/pissang/echarts-next/graphs/punch-card'
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Punch Card'],
        left: 'right'
    },
    polar: {},
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function (params) {
            return params.value[2] + ' commits in ' + hours[params.value[1]] + ' of ' + days[params.value[0]];
        }
    },
    angleAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: hours,
        boundaryGap: false,
        splitLine: {
            show: true,
            lineStyle: {
                color: '#999',
                type: 'dashed'
            }
        },
        axisLine: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    radiusAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: days,
        axisLine: {
            show: false
        },
        axisLabel: {
            rotate: 45
        }
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'a', // I added an id like the other example
        name: 'Punch Card',
        type: 'scatter',
        coordinateSystem: 'polar',
        symbolSize: function (val) {
            return val[2] * 2;
        },
        data: data,
        animationDelay: function (idx) {
            return idx * 5;
        }
    }]
};

if (!app.inNode) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myChart.setOption({
            graphic: echarts.util.map(data, function (item, dataIndex) {
                // I could not get `myChart.convertToPixel` to work
                // So I searched and found myChart._coordSysMgr._coordinateSystems[0].dataToPoint
                // and also myChart._coordSysMgr._coordinateSystems[0].pointToData
                return {
                    type: 'circle',
                    position: myChart._coordSysMgr._coordinateSystems[0].dataToPoint(item),
                    shape: {
                        cx: 0,
                        cy: 0,
                        // The size is based on the 3rd data
                        r: (item[2] * 2) / 2
                    },
                    invisible: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    ondrag: echarts.util.curry(onPointDragging, dataIndex),
                    onmousemove: echarts.util.curry(showTooltip, dataIndex),
                    onmouseout: echarts.util.curry(hideTooltip, dataIndex),
                    z: 100
                };
            })
        });
    }, 0);
    window.addEventListener('resize', updatePosition);
}

myChart.on('dataZoom', updatePosition);

function updatePosition() {
    myChart.setOption({
        graphic: echarts.util.map(data, function (item, dataIndex) {
            return {
                position: myChart._coordSysMgr._coordinateSystems[0].dataToPoint(item)
            };
        })
    });
}

function showTooltip(dataIndex) {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'showTip',
        seriesIndex: 0,
        dataIndex: dataIndex
    });
}

function hideTooltip(dataIndex) {
    myChart.dispatchAction({type: 'hideTip'});
}

function onPointDragging(dataIndex, dx, dy) {
    // Since our data are on a grid, we have to check if data changed before we
    // update the graph for no reason

    var newData = myChart._coordSysMgr._coordinateSystems[0].pointToData(this.position);
    // If data not changed
    if (newData[0] == data[dataIndex][0] && newData[1] == data[dataIndex][1]) return;

    // Update only the position data (not the 3rd)
    data[dataIndex][0] = newData[0];
    data[dataIndex][1] = newData[1];

    // Update data
    myChart.setOption({
        series: [{
            id: 'a',
            data: data
        }]
    });
}
```